# 500 up email send at a time in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am in a project where i have to send email to group where each group has 300/400/500 email address. I have to send email at a time to group. I have already done this by normal process (fetching email address and send email by loop). It is working fine when a group has 10-20 email address but when a group has 100 up or more email it execute for long time and after a while it gives error. Any technical issues do i have to take in laravel 5 or other?

I am using gmail smtp server.

Answer (score 0):

use queue system on laravel.

[Laravel queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues)

```
Mail::queue('email.send_email', $somedata, function($m){
    $m->to('example@example.com');
})
```